# Lambda Apply : Referencing other rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I'm trying to alter the values of a given column in my dataset based on values around the given cell.
Consider the following data:

```
Data = {'Col1': [5593 , 5114 , 6803 , 2175 , 2175] , 'Col2': [2879 , 1176 , 7114 , 8677 , 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = Data)
df.head()

Col1    Col2
0   5593    2879
1   5114    1176
2   6803    7114
3   2175    8677
4   2175    0
```

I create a new column to store the new values :

```
Data['Col3'] = Data['Col2']
```

I want to make an apply - lambda function which does the following:
If Col3 is zero and the previous value for Col1 equals the current value for Col1, i.e: (x.shift(-2 , -1) == x.shift(-2, 0), then the actual value for Col3 should be the previous value for Col2, i.e x.shift(-1 , -1). Otherwise the value for Col3 should be unchanged.

I've tried something like the following (Pseudo-code):

```
df['Col3'] = df['Col3'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1 , -1) if (x == 0 and x.shift(-2 , -1) == x.shift(-2, 0)) else x)
```

For this specific subset of my data is should look like the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
0   5593    2879    2879
1   5114    1176    1176
2   6803    7114    7114
3   2175    8677    8677
4   2175    0       8677
```

I'm not sure if shift is the right method to use (The series contains NaN), but hopefully the idea is clear.

My real dataset is very large, so i want the operations to perform well with many rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with the shifted columns:

```
df['Col3'] = np.where(df['Col1'].shift().eq(df['Col1']), df['Col2'].shift(), df['Col2'])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Col1  Col2    Col3
0  5593  2879  2879.0
1  5114  1176  1176.0
2  6803  7114  7114.0
3  2175  8677  8677.0
4  2175     0  8677.0
```

Below is step by step, explanation with comments:

```
# create a mask, where is True if the consecutive values in Col1 are equal
mask = df['Col1'].shift().eq(df['Col1'])

# choose between the shifted Col2 (the previous value) and Col2 using the mask
df['Col3'] = np.where(mask, df['Col2'].shift(), df['Col2'])

print(df)
```

Comment: It works great if the value appears in the first row! Is there any way to expand the code such that in also checks the same conditions but for the row below as well? In my terminology it would be shift(1 , 1)

Comment: @Amby95 Could you add a small example where it does not works?

Comment: If u switched index 3 and 4 in the first output, you would have the exact case i'm referring to. Then it should still examine if the same value is in the row above or below, and if that's the case, then the same procedure should be executed.